# Separate Zend Application for control panel?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-application

Shall I create a separate Zend Application for the user backend of a web application?

My main concern is that I have to have a separate Zend_Auth on both the public website (for clients to login) and for employees to manage the site.

Since it appears to me that I can't use multiple Zend_Auth instances in one application this would be the only solution.

The next concern would be that the two Zend_Auth sessions will collide since they run on the same webspace?

Cheers

Comment: Does an employee need to be logged in as a client at the same time, or does a user only ever log in as one type?

Comment: The user has to have the possibility to use both logins at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Benjamin Cremer's solution won't work, because `Zend_Auth_Admin` *extends* a Singleton implementation, so its `getInstance()` would yield a `Zend_Auth` instance, **not** a `Zend_Auth_Admin` one.

I myself was confronted with this situation, and seeing that the ZF people (at least in ZF1) see authetication as a *single* entry-point in an application (they could've made it so that Zend_Auth could contain multiple instances, using LSB in php etc.), made a minor modification to Benjamin Cremer's code - you must also override the getInstance():

```
<?php

class AdminAuth extends Zend_Auth
{
    /**
     * @var AdminAuth
     */
    static protected $_adminInstance;

    /**
     * @return Zend_Auth_Storage_Interface
     */
    public function getStorage()
    {
        if (null === $this->_storage) {
            $this->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('Zend_Auth_Admin'));
        }
        return $this->_storage;
    }

    /**
     * Singleton pattern implementation.
     *
     * @return AdminAuth
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === self::$_adminInstance) {
            self::$_adminInstance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_adminInstance;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Auth implements the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so there can only exist one instance of this class.

To distinguish whether the current identity is an admin or an user you could use an isAdmin-Flag, or even better implement the [Zend_Acl_Role_Interface](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html).

If it is really required by your application to have two Auth-Sessions at the same time (one for a User, on for an Admin) you could 'copy' the Zend_Auth class by extending it and adjust the session storage.

```
<?php
class Zend_Auth_Admin extends Zend_Auth
{
    /**
     * Returns the persistent storage handler
     *
     * Session storage is used by default unless a different storage adapter has been set.
     *
     * @return Zend_Auth_Storage_Interface
     */
    public function getStorage()
    {
        if (null === $this->_storage) {
            $namespace = 'Zend_Auth_Admin'; // default is 'Zend_Auth'
            /**
             * @see Zend_Auth_Storage_Session
             */
            require_once 'Zend/Auth/Storage/Session.php';
            $this->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session($namespace));
        }

        return $this->_storage;
    }
}
```

So you can use two distinct Auth objects for your Session handling

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance(); // instance for users
Zend_Auth_Admin::getInstance(); //  instance for admins
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. the thing is: I've got two seperate database tables. One is an employee login, one for clients

Comment: I don't see a Problem. You can login with to different auth adapters. One for each table.